# XPath check for non-existing node

Tags: xpath

Im having a bit of trouble finding the right XPath syntax to check if a particular node in my XML exists. I'm only allowed to use XPath (so no XSL or something else like that, it has to be a pure XPath expression syntax).

I have an XML and it has a node `Filename` but it doesn't exist in every case. When the filename isn't specified, my LiveCycle proces will use a different route to fill in the filename. But how do I check if the `Filename` node exists?

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for an explanation and for a short single XPath expression that selects either the filename or the default, in case the filename is missing. :)

Answer (score 18):

Similar to count but maybe more direct depending of what you want is the function **boolean**

`boolean(//Filename)`

This returns **true** if "Filename" node exist and **false** if not.

Comment: Somewhat cryptic intent though, huh?

Answer (score 17):

You can use the [`count`](http://www.zvon.org/xxl/XPathTutorial/Output/example7.html) function - passing in the path of the nodes you are checking.

If they do not exist, then the value of `count` will be 0:

```
count(//Filename) = 0
```

Answer (score 10):

**Suppose you have the following XML document**:

```
<top>
  <function>
    <filenamex>c:\a\y\z\myFile.xml</filenamex>
    <default>Default.xml</default>
  </function>
</top>
```

**then this XPath expression selects either the `filename` element when it's present or the `default` element when no `filename` element is specified**:

```
(/*/function/filename
|
 /*/function/default
 )
  [1]
```

**The shortest way to check if the `filename` element exists is**:

`/*/function/filename`

**So the first XPath expression could be re-written in the equivalent** (but somewhat longer):

```
 /*/function/filename
|
 /*/function/default[not(/*/function/filename)]
```

Answer (score 9):

Given the example Xml from another answer

```
<top>
  <function>
    <filenamex>c:\a\y\z\myFile.xml</filenamex>
    <default>Default.xml</default>
  </function>
</top>
```

- To get nodes WITH node "filenamex" use `/top/function[filenamex]`
- To get nodes WITHOUT node "filenamex" use `/top/function[not(filenamex)]`

I felt it necessary to answer here as the other answers did not work as advertised in XmlSpy